# Angular2 why do we need the es6-shim

Tags: angular, es6-shim

Following the [Angular2 Quickstart Guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) we are instructed to include `es6-shim` in 2 places:

1) `index.html`

`<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>`

2) `typings.json`

```
"ambientDependencies": {
  "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#6697d6f7dadbf5773cb40ecda35a76027e0783b2"
}
```

I was under the impression that we are compiling our `es6` code down to `es5`.

Configured in `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    ...
```

If the end result is that the browser is loading `es5`, why does the browser needs shims for `es6`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Typings are used by your editor to give you code hinting/intellisense, and `es6-shim.min.js` is a code that emulates ES6 features for ES5 browsers. Some of those features are `Promise`, `Array.from()`...

While your code is translated to ES5, you need to include `es6-shim` so you can use those new features in it... Consider this ES6 code:

```
let test1 = () => 123 + 456;
let test2 = new Promise((resolve, reject ) => {});
```

it will be translated to ES5 code:

```
var test1 = function () { return 123 + 456; };
var test2 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { });
```

but without `es6-shim` **Promise** would be undefined...

Comment: you mean `hinting/intellisense` given by editor is using es6-shim ?

Comment: And as of Oct 2016, they are now recommending core-js over es6-shim in their quick start referenced by the OP.

Answer (score 13):

TypeScript does not come with built-in polyfills. There are certain features it doesn't transpile, this is where polyfills like `es-shim` come in.

The TypeScript definition file will provide you with typing support within your chosen editor and the `es-shim` will provide the implementation for the functionality that TypeScript doesn't transpile to ES5 code.

A few of such features TypeScript doesn't transpile are:

- Promises
- Functions hanging off of prototype objects (`Array.from()`,`Array.of()`,`Number.isInteger()`, etc)
- Module loading

The general approach is:

> The rule of thumb is that if there's a canonical/sane emit that doesn't have a huge perf-hit, we'll try to support it. We don't add any runtime methods or data structures, which is more what core.js *(or any pollyfil)* serves to do. - [source (TypeScript developer)](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3956#issuecomment-123485403)