# module resolution with angular2 / ASP.NET5 (cannot find angular2/core)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have started a new ASP.NET5/MVC6 project.

**Attempt 1** My problem is that when I set `moduleResolution` to `classic` in `tsconfig.json` i receive an error as follows:

> Cannot find module 'angular2/core'

**Attempt 2** If I change `tsconfig.json` to use `node` resolution, the exclude `node_modules`  in `tsconfig.js` does not work, [**this is a bug?**](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11055), which is closed, though it still seems to be a problem, and multiple errors are encountered when studio 2015 trolls through the `node_modules` folder including every `.d.ts` in the entire tree. There are hundreds of errors, mostly in `rxjs`.

**Attempt 3** If I remove `tsconfig.json` completely, I can get the application executing, and the files compiled, but alas, this error in the browser.

> Error: (SystemJS) require is not defined

*I cannot help but think that the angular2 / typescript support in Visual Studio **is a complete mess**, and I should go back to angular 1 and MVC5*. For the record, I am using typescript 2.0.6, and my visual studio is completely up to date.

> Is there a combination of `package.json` and `tsconfig.json` that actually works out of the box with Visual Studio 2015 for angular2.

`package.json` has the following dependencies.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.17"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/angular2": "0.0.2",
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.17",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-jasmine": "^2.4.2",
    "gulp-print": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "gulp-typings": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.10",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.26"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json` is as follows

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "classic"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

`boot.ts` is as follows

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/angular2/core.d.ts"/>
//  the above is a correct path, but it doesn't seem to matter.
import {bootstrap} from "angular2/platform/browser";
//                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ (Error Here)
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/http";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";

bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
console.log("starting angular...");
```

app.component.js

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/angular2/core.d.ts"/>

import { Component, OnInit } from "angular2/core";
//                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ (Error Here)

@Component({
    selector: "app",
    templateUrl: "static.html"
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    message: string;

    constructor() {
        console.log("starting app component");
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this
            .message =
            "The 'static.html' was used as the Angular2 'templateUrl'. There is a 'message' property bound to the <blockqoute> element.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NB:** Make certain that **`es6-shim.d.ts`** is installed in the wwwroot directory. Many of the `node_modules` files traversed by typescript cannot be compiled without [es6-shim.d.ts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642223/angular2-why-do-we-need-the-es6-shim)

I have a sample on integrating angular2(2.1.0) and ASP.NET core, I think the ng2's packages dependencies will also work on ASP.NET5.

[package.json](https://github.com/KarateJB/Angular2.Mvc/blob/master/Angular2.Mvc/src/Angular2.Mvc.Website/package.json)

[systemjs.config.js](https://github.com/KarateJB/Angular2.Mvc/blob/master/Angular2.Mvc/src/Angular2.Mvc.Website/wwwroot/app/systemjs.config.js)

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks, i have updated .net core, and got most of your application up, it will take some time to go through, but it probably will help. I am leaving the question open for some more direct answers in the meantime.

Comment: hi, just wondering what role es6-shim.d.ts plays. es6-shim seems to be what's needed to make it all hang together. I get numerous errors in .d.ts files throughout the node_modules directory until es6-shim.d.ts is placed somewhere in wwwroot. tsconfig.json targets es5, so why would the shim be necessary?

Comment: HI, Jim, es6-shim is for the compatibility of es6 features. Here are some references.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35642381/7045253